What is the fair market value of a solar system installed by solar city in 2014 in California Model # PVI-3.6-OUTD-S-US (240 V)
What is the fair market value of a solar system installed by solar city in 2014 in California. Model # PVI-3.6-OUTD-S-US (240 V)
